# Retrieving results from a map

Tags: apex, map, collection

I'm trying to work with and understand maps. 
I have the following map and I don't know how to retrieve one of the results from it, can some one explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
Map<String, RecordType >RecTypeList = new map<String, RecordType>([select Name, id from RecordType
                         where sObjecttype = 'Service_call_Task__c' 
                         AND  DeveloperName IN ('Service','Alarm')]) ;
system.debug(RecTypeList);
system.debug(RecTypeList.get('Alarm'));
```

The first debug line returns the id of the recordtype and then the results of the SOQL Query

> {0124E00000010OaQAI=RecordType:{Name=Service, Id=0124E00000010OaQAI}, 0124E00000010P9QAI=RecordType:{Name=Alarm, Id=0124E00000010P9QAI}}

I was expecting something like Alarm = 0124E00000010P9QAI

The second debug line returns a null result.

I've tried to change the map from

```
<String, RecordType> to <String, Id >
```

but i get an error:

> Invalid initializer type List found for Map: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a valid SObject List

Comment: Specifically regarding record types, consider a describe call: `Id alarmRecordTypeId = Service_Call_Task__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Alarm').getRecordTypeId();` This gives you the answer you want without the SOQL hit (there's a limit of 100 per transaction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the approach:

```
Map<Id, RecordType> RecTypeMap = new map<Id, RecordType>([SELECT id, Name  from RecordType
                                                     where sObjecttype = 'Service_call_Task__c' 
                                                     AND  DeveloperName IN ('Service','Alarm')]) ;
for(Id recId:RecTypeMap.keySet())
{
    RecordType rdObject = RecTypeMap.get(recId);
    String recName = rdObject.Name;
}
```

Ideally, to retrieve the `RecordType` information you do not need to perform separate SOQL query. You can do that by using `Schema` class.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Service_call_Task__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> lstRT = R.getRecordTypeInfos();
for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo rt:lstRT)
{
    System.debug('RecordTypeName=' + rt.getName());
    if(rt.getName().contains('Service') || rt.getName().contains('Alarm'))
    {
         System.debug('RecordTypeId=' + rt.getRecordTypeId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass SOQL into constructor of a `Map`, `Id` of records are keys. In order to retrieve value from Map use record Id

```
System.debug(RecTypeList.get('0124E00000010OaQAI'));
```